# How do i insert .csv file into monodb using nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I am unable to import .csv file into mongodb by using nodejs.
returns
error:Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html

Comment: Please post your code. Provide an minimal reproduction of the problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's pretty hard to troubleshoot code we can't see...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this ?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you post your code ? It will be easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Did this a while back. I ended up executing it as a system command as follows:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec
let command = 'mongoimport -d database -c collection --file import.json'
exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  cb()
})
```